# Error after elif statement is added to df.iterrows() loop

Tags: python, pandas

So I was not obtaining any syntax errors with the first if statement. When I add the second elif, i get a syntax error for the next line:
NPI = df["NPI2"]
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Not sure why this is happening since the first if statement is essentially the same as the elif

Here's my code:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    NPI2 = row["NPI2"]
    
    if row["CapDesignation"] == "R" and row["BR"] >= row["CapThreshold"]:
        NPI2 = row["CapThreshold"]*row['KBETR']-.005
        df.at[i,"NPI2"] = NPI2
        df.at[i,"BR"] = NPI2/row["KBETR"]
    

    elif row["CapDesignation"] == "N" and row["BN"] >= row["CapThreshold"]:
        NPI2 = row["CapThreshold"]*(row["KBETR"]-row["P"])-.005
        df.at[i,"NPI2"] = NPI2
        df.at[i,"BN"] = NPI2/((row["KBETR"]-row["P"])
    


NPI = df["NPI2"]
df["KBETR_N"] = round(R + Delta_P + NPI,2)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and in a [reproducible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391). Otherwise people won't be able to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the error is without the traceback message, but it should be:
`df.at[i,"BN"] = NPI2/((row["KBETR"]-row["P"])` where you have 2 parentheses in `((row["KBETR"]` instead of 1(if you wish to have `row["KBETR"]-row["P"]` surrounded by parentheses).